# Laravel : How do i get the names, Phone numbers and other details using loop in blade view

Tags: database, laravel, nested-loops

[image]

This is a json format from my database. How do i get a tabulated information of the names and phone numbers etc.

Comment: send the data from controller in compact() and then loop through in blade
`return View::make('blog')->with('posts', $posts);`

Answer (score 0):

I will create a simple example with minimal table

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Car type</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $post->Cartype }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->email }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `car` types and `banks` as seperate entities, you have to declare the `$banks` and `$carTypes` as 2 arrays and get the necessary data for the arrays from the database.

After that you can then pass those arrays to the view. You can use the below code to pass multiple arrays to the view.

```
return view('yourview', compact('banks ','carTypes '));
```

After that in your view you can render your values using the foreach loop to get the values.

```
foreach($banks as $bank){
 // Your code
}

foreach($carTypes as $carType){
  // Your code
}
```

Hope this helps you :)